# select a dtype in a column np genfromtxt

Tags: python, numpy

Hi I'm pretty new in python and i need to extract some boolean values from a csv file. Here it is a short example of my dataset:

```
Timestamp   FilteredEcg IsPeak  RRinterval  HR  Sickness    Ride    Note
300.0   -2.4042697707709204e-08 False   -   -   0   1   
300.005 0.00015629470247651288  False   -   -   0   1
```

here a summary of column's data type:

- Timestamp: float
- FilteredEcg: float
- IsPeak: boolean
- HR: boolean
- Sickness: int
- Ride: int
- Note: string

As you can see sometimes there are missing values. My problem is retrieving boolean values. Here what I'm doing:

```
dataset = np.genfromtxt('{}/{}'.format(directory, filename), delimiter="\t", skip_header=1)
orig_rr = dataset[::,3] # OK
orig_ecg = dataset[::,1] # OK
orig_peak = dataset[::,2] # WRONG!
print(orig_peak) # here I get [nan, nan, ... , nan]
```

I think it's a casting problem. How can i select the data type of `IsPeak` column? If it's not possible to cast only one column it would be ok to cast them all. (I'm using numpy)

### Edit

It seems that i can do something like this:

```
types = [np.float64, np.float64, np.bool,np.float64,np.float64, np.int, np.int, np.str]
dataset = np.genfromtxt('{}/{}'.format(directory, filename), delimiter="\t", skip_header=1, dtype=types)
```

but it not preserve the ndarray shape, initially I have `(456000, 8)` and printing dataset i have:

```
[[ 1.20000000e+02 -1.09909475e-07             nan ...  0.00000000e+00
   1.00000000e+00             nan]
 [ 1.20005000e+02  1.12516659e-03             nan ...  0.00000000e+00
   1.00000000e+00             nan]
 [ 1.20010000e+02  5.23451481e-03             nan ...  0.00000000e+00
   1.00000000e+00             nan]
 ...
 [ 2.39998500e+03 -2.12878689e-02             nan ...  2.00000000e+00
   6.00000000e+00             nan]
 [ 2.39999000e+03 -8.18406955e-03             nan ...  2.00000000e+00
   6.00000000e+00             nan]
 [ 2.39999500e+03  1.35783998e-06             nan ...  2.00000000e+00
   6.00000000e+00             nan]]
```

when i apply the dtype change i have `(456000,)` as size and printing dataset i have:

```
[( 120.   , -1.09909475e-07, False, nan, nan, 0, 1, '')
 ( 120.005,  1.12516659e-03, False, nan, nan, 0, 1, '')
 ( 120.01 ,  5.23451481e-03, False, nan, nan, 0, 1, '') ...
 (2399.985, -2.12878689e-02, False, nan, nan, 2, 6, '')
 (2399.99 , -8.18406955e-03, False, nan, nan, 2, 6, '')
 (2399.995,  1.35783998e-06, False, nan, nan, 2, 6, '')]
```

any idea on how i can preserve the initial shape or how can extract all column values like I did before adding the `dtype` ? Before this addon I was able to do something like this to retrieve all first values:

```
dataset[::,1]
```

now I cannot do it

Comment: You have to make an structured array if your dtypes are different in the same array. Good thing about it is you can assign names to each column and call them by their names, like `dataset['IsPeak']`.

Comment: The default column `dtype` is float.  If it can't create a number for the cell's value, it uses `np.nan`.  If you specify a `dtype` list, or use `dtype=None` (auto dtype) you'll get a `structured array`, which is displayed with `()`.  That array will be 1d, with multiple fields.  Fields are accessed by name, not number.  You'll need to read more `numpy` documentation to make effective use of such an array (start with a through reading of `genfromtxt`).

Comment: Instead of `np.str` specify a string dtype with length, e.g. 'U10'

Comment: pandas might be easier to use with this file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like all your cells are not Tab spaced. I checked and made modifications in a .txt file with the sample data you gave. Then, I read it with Tab delimiter and associated dashes with nans:

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.txt', delimiter='\t', na_values='-')
```

and can correctly retrieve the booleans with e.g.:

```
data.IsPeak
```